# How do I switch Apple Watch's "Now Playing" source between "phone mode" and "watch mode"

Tags: itunes, audio, apple-watch, airpods, watchos

The Apple Watch "now playing" control allows me to quickly adjust volume from my wrist without pulling out my phone.

Once I purchased AirPods and connected them to my watch, my entire user experience changed: I discovered that music can be played "from" the watch, or "from" the phone.

The problem is that I don't see a consistent way to bring up the device chooser (AirPods or iPhone) when

1. Music is playing/streaming from one device and not the other
2. Music isn't playing anywhere
3. Music or Audio is playing on both devices (strange ...but seemingly default use case)
4. Non-iTunes audio (as in Audiobooks or Safari) on the phone

I'm having a difficult time with this UX and any navigational tips would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

*This is a slightly old question, so they probably just fixed the UI over the years.*

For me the top left corner of Now Playing says the source the app is currently controlling. If you tap that it brings up the other options.